# Paint problems with horizontal JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

This is my code. I notice some viewing problems when scrolling horizontally until I call `scroll.repaint()`. (the JScrollPanel scroll is inside another JPanel called panel).

```
JPanel pan=new JPanel("My Panel");
pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(XMIN,YMIN));
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(pan,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
pan.setSize(XPAN,YPAN);
scroll.setBounds(0,100,XMIN,YMIN);
//...stuff, I put elements in my JPanel pan.
pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x>XMIN?x+deltaX:XMIN,YMIN));
pan.revalidate();
panel.add(scroll);
scroll.repaint();
panel.repaint();
```

Is there a simple way to fix the JScrollPane and to have Always a clear view of my items in JScrollPane even when scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with non-opaque elements, by default JCheckBox are not opaque...
Now it works well :)

Comment: In my experience Swing components are opaque by default (except JLabel), unless you are using some strange LAF. I suspect you real problem is that you are using a null layout. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Also, don't use setPreferredSize(). It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size. There is also no need for all the revalidate() and repaint() methods. All Swing components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.